# How to upload file to public swarm?

Tags: swarm

I have ubuntu server. I tried to make

```
root@vid:~# swarm up 1.txt
65b03c05950213ae7d3d55659aabe1828c07ea79c30a4e61e44342a8b5d41653
root@vid:~#
```

How can I see this file from my local Mist browser?

```
bzz://5c7568a22427698bb6f92dd2e0cb560e2d17ec64228e3965052830d6e1fe393e
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [official documentation](https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/up-and-download.html), as they have a step by step guide for your issue.

Comment: Link only answer is not recommended it can get inaccesible if the site is down or the page moved. It is better to include a few lines with the general idea and use the link to expand the details.